# Pass argument to partial view C# MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I need to pass a parameter to a partial view but I'm not finding how.

So basically my problem is: I need to call RenameFileAndFolder from a different view and then bring the user to the Index controller page but passing a path to the _fileTable.

**Controller:**

```
public ActionResult Index(){...}

public ActionResult _fileTable(string path){...} //partial view

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult RenameFileAndFolder(string path, string newName){...}
```

**View:**

```
function RenameFileFolder() {
    //(...)
    $.ajax({
        type: "Post",
        url: '@Url.Action("RenameFileAndFolder", "ManageFiles")',
        data: { path: '@(currentPath)', newName: inputName }, 
        dataType: "json",
        traditional: true,
        success: function (data) {
            document.getElementById("inputNewName").value = ""; 
            //Here how can I say: "go to the index page with the path="X" on the partial view"?
            //currently I am doing this but it does not allow me to pass a parameter
            window.location.assign("Index");
    })
}
```

The partial view is called within the view:

```
<div id="tabelaDiv">
    @{
        Html.RenderAction("_fileTable", Model);
    }
</div>
```

EDIT:
My situation in more detail:
So, I am on the View beta with partial view omega within it. Then I go to View alpha and call function RenameFileFolder() with an ajax query, and, if success, I want to be able to go again to View Beta and pass a parameter to the partial view omega.

Comment: where are you calling the partial view ?

Comment: @Shyju Thanks for your answer. I am calling the partial view inside my view. Please see my edit above,

Comment: so you want to pass the value of `path` (a string) as the model of the partial view ?

Comment: Or you want to call the partial view with the location of partial view as the value of `path` ? What is the value of `path` ?

Comment: @Shyju Thanks for your help. Sorry, I am not been able to explain myself well. So, I am on the View beta with partial view omega within it. Then I go to View alpha and call function RenameFileFolder() with an ajax query, and, if success, I want to be able to go again to View Beta and pass a parameter to the partial view omega.

Comment: " I want to be able to go again to View Beta and pass a parameter to the partial view omega". This is what you originally had before going to view alpha. Why not do a redirect on your ajax success call to the action method which renders the view beta. I still do not understand when you say pass parameter ? What parameter, as per your edit, you are calling just calling partial view omega

Comment: @Shyju Yes, I can redirect to the action method that renders view beta. But inside view beta, there is a call to the partial view Html.RenderAction("_fileTable", Model);  and how can I say that I want "c://folderX/folderY" passed as a parameter to the partial view, coming from the ajax call?

Comment: Is the partial view located inside your application ? What location it is in ?

Comment: and what are you currently having inside the `_fileTable` action method ? Which view/how are you returning it ?

Answer (score 0):

Simply write this to send parameters to ActionMethod

```
<div id="tabelaDiv">        
        @Html.Action("_fileTable",new{path= "your path"} )   
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Ismail. But I am calling the partial view within the view (see my code update above). If I do like you suggest, how does the view "knows" where I would like to render the partial view (in which part of the page)?

Comment: Thanks Ismail but I think I didn't explain well. I believe your solution was not applicable for my case. Please see my update on the first post. Thanks and sorry for not been clearer.

Answer (score 0):

You could try storing the new filepath in a Session variable and then accessing it in your view. This will save you trouble of trying to pass the variable between your views.

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult RenameFileAndFolder(string path, string newName)
    {
        //code to get new file path

        //set session variable
        Session["path"] = "<filepath>";

        //return your ActionResult;
    }
```

Once you have stored the variable, you can access the session variable in your view by using:

```
@Session["path"]
```

It really depends on how long you would like this data to persist for. This variable will persist throughout the users entire session, so if you want to reset it you would need to do so explicitly `Session["path"] = null`. However, if you only want it to persist long enough to render a single partial view, it may be better to use one of the other methods for persisting data such as ViewData:

https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/576514/AplusBeginner-splusTutorialplusonplusVariousplus